# docker swarm overlay network issues

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, docker, devops, docker-swarm

I have a docker swarm cluster with overlay network. However, when I create services with this overlay network, it is not balancing traffic across my different nodes. I am not sure why that would be. As a result, I am not able to ping none of my nodes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Port 4789/udp is responsible for overlay network communication. Your SG needs to allow UDP instead of TCP for that port. Also what os are you running?

Comment: I am running ubuntu on my three different nodes